# Motion Blur not working on all objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, motion-blur

Motion blur is working only in the moving object of image 1 but it's not working for the object from the second image? I'm stuck I don't know why is this happening? Both belong to the same scene.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe the Tie isn't moving fast enough ? Did you tried augmenting the shutter time ?

Comment: I did. Still can't figure this out. But I just deleted the model and I duplicate it from another copy and it's working.